# Select from tables, where the table names are stored in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query in which I can select data from a series of tables. I want to be able to pull those table names FROM ANOTHER TABLE; I don't want to just write 
`select * from tableA union select * from tableB` etc.

A further restriction that's complicating the issue is that my query MUST start with `select`.

I've tried to use OPENQUERY within the select statement but the server I'm trying to access is 'not configured for DATA ACCESS.'

Comment: Take a look at a cursor and dynamic sql.

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
DECLARE   @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT    @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + ' ', '') +
          'SELECT * FROM ' + TableName +
          CASE
            WHEN TableName = MAX(TableName) OVER () THEN ''
            ELSE ' UNION ALL '
          END
FROM      TableNames;

EXEC(@SQL);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The only problem with it seems to be the declaration of the variables. This will certainly do the trick for the union part, but I need something like this:

`select * from

(

DECLARE   @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT    @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + ' ', '') +
          'SELECT * FROM ' + TableName +
          CASE
            WHEN TableName = MAX(TableName) OVER () THEN ''
            ELSE ' UNION ALL '
          END

FROM      dvValidationTablesMASTER;

EXEC(@SQL);

)
`

Apologies for the horrible formatting, I'm still getting the hang of this...

Comment: @user3873696: The EXEC call with execute the SQL in the variable, so it will actually bring up the data you are looking for; there's no need to put a SELECT * FROM around it.  Or if you disagree, let me know the context you are trying to solve your problem in and I'll think about it.

Comment: I agree that the select is unnecessary. It's not worth explaining why, but unfortunately the very first word of any code that I write _has_ to be `select`. It's a limitation of the tool I use to access the database. I've tried your method above, and I've looked into cursors and dynamic sql but everything appears to start with some for of `declare` statement. I think I may have to go back to the drawing board and try to find another way approach this. Thanks again for the help, it's very much appreciated! I haven't been able to solve my problem but I've learned a lot!

Comment: @user3873696: Well, it's not game over, necessarily.  Can you preface that whole statement with SELECT 1; or something?  If so, that will execute, then the rest of the statement will execute.